# Can vim be used to view a growing file?

Tags: vim, less, tail, logfiles

I often use vim's `view` for viewing files. Is there a way to use it for a growing file so that I can see the progress as it's happening? Something similar to

```
tail -f
```

or

```
less +F
```

I have two use cases:

1. view a growing log file,
2. view something that takes long to process, like the output of `tar tzf ...`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The main benefit when viewing files with vim for me is syntax highlighting; I'm not sure there is much of this for log files or tar archive listings. The other is seeking, but this can be done with `less` as well (enter `/`, or perhaps `?` for backwards search direction).

Comment: @Tobias I'm used to vim so it'd be nice to have one tool for everything. For example I'd be able to combine viewing such a growing file with editing/viewing another files in a split window.

Comment: Have you tried to split the window first and then run the `tail` or `less` command you want via `:!`?

Comment: "One tool for everything" is the complete opposite of the Vim/Unix philosophy and, therefore, will be hard to achieve. Why don't you simply run your long-running program in another shell, possibly with the help of a terminal multiplexer like screen or tmux…

Comment: is `set: autoread` and `:checktime` what you need? see [answer by Ingo Karkat](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149209/refresh-changed-content-of-file-opened-in-vim)